# What is the Best Way to Display a Non-Modal "Loading" Message on IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app, and sometimes when the user presses a button, the chosen operation will take a minute or two. I would like to display a message instructing the user to wait, but not block the user from using the app in the meantime. Also I would like customizable text on the message.

Another requirement is that I use a TabBarController as the main navigation control.

My idea is to have a message appear at the top of the screen, pushing the content down by 20 pixels. Note that as there would be multiple screens, this 20 pixel message would have to be independent of any single screen.

I have tried a few different ways, each with drawbacks.

1 - Have a Root View and call AddSubView with the TabBarController. Then I can resize the TabBarController and show the message on the Root View underneath. This fails because the TabBarController child views do not receive "ViewDidAppear" messages. Interestingly, if I display a modal window at some later point, the "ViewDidAppear" messages begin to work. But I would like ViewDidAppear at the start.

2 - Similar to #1. Have a Root View and display the TabBarController as a modal view. This allows ViewDidAppear to work, but if the screen is rotated, the rotation message doesn't propogate to the Root View. So I cannot rotate the Root View.

3 - Subclass TabBarController to properly handle rotation. The Apple docs say not to do this, so I worry my app would be rejected, if I can make it work.

4 - Add two views to the main window. One for displaying the message, and one for the app content. This suffers from the same rotation problem as option #2.

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: For case #2: pass notification from root VC to TabBarController manually.

Comment: Considered a 'badge' saying '12%' on the related tab button?

Comment: @Kris Van Bael - No, but that sounds like a possible idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but you could consider to use a message on top of the status bar. [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/) uses it and I find it a very interesting and good example of unobtrusive feedback (that also saves you some pixels :). If you want to make it easily, have a look at [this library](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) (be sure to read the warning).
A second option, also suggested by Kris Van Bael on a comment, is to add a custom view just like [Instagram](http://instagr.am/). Again, there is detailed info in [this article](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/03/08/how-does-the-instagram-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar-notification/).
I hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure whether I will use these ideas, but I will definitely consider them. Thanks. Too bad about the status bar warning. That looks like a very good solution.

Comment: A badge is not a custom view. It is a stamdard feature of UITabItem

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a "custom badge", because of the "%" after the "12", just like this overlay view on the linked article.